# ILLEGAL token for line break in JSON response?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

After sending back some JSON, JavaScript errors out with:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

when I respond with a string with a line break like:

```
{ "call": "myFunction("<ul>↵    <li>Passwords are case-sensitive, that is the lower-case letter \"a\" is diffe...")" }
```

[This is the PHP](http://pastebin.com/KYuXjjBd) and [this is the raw JSON response I get back](http://pastebin.com/U1MzXQw0).

Yes I **do** override some of the JSON after it has been encoded. I've done this so the clientside knows it has to call a function. I will try alternatives to this.

It doesn't error out when I send a response without a line break. **How can I fix the line break?** What should I convert it to? How do I search and replace it? Should I use a special flag when I call `json_encode()`?

I've tried:

```
$json = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $json);
$json = str_replace("\r",   "\n", $json);
$json = str_replace("\n",   "\\n", $json);
```

Comment: If you generate your JSON properly, this should never happen.  Show us how you generated the JSON.  Also, show us the raw response.

Comment: Unquoted `call` and the double quote after `myFunction(` is also invalid JSON...

Comment: @DCoder Yeah I manually typed that key in. I'll fix it. As for the double quote it works and when I try escaping it, it then doesn't work.

Comment: So how exactly do you produce that broken json?

Comment: @Dcoder & zerkms: I'm extracting that part now. I've been naughty and I play with the JSON after it's encoded, which is probably producing this error. I'll update the OP with what I will share.

Comment: Updated OP with my PHP.

Comment: Updated OP with the JSON I get back from the server.

Comment: If there's anything wrong, I would check this part: `$json = str_replace($jsfuncs['replace'], $jsfuncs['with'], $json);`

Comment: Yeah, manually modifying JSON is a bad idea. Sending JS code as part of JSON is even worse. Consider encoding needed function calls differently, e.g. as an assoc-array with keys describing the function to call and arguments to pass to it.

Comment: @DCoder That sounds like a good alternative. Until I have the time to re-write it, is there a way to fix what I have now?

Comment: Is it really worth the time to fix this? It should be fairly simple to just rewrite it properly.

Comment: @DCoder The response is handled by a library that can't be updated and released in a second, as easy as it might be. My preference is a short term fix until I spend the time to write, test and release a new system.

Comment: In Chrome the new line is shown as ↵ - how can I find and replace that?

Comment: Then you need to make sure the replacement `$value` is valid JSON before you insert it - run it through `json_encode` first, and see if that is enough.

Comment: I think I've fixed it by `json_encode()`ing every argument for function calls. I think they were avoiding the encoding completely. It appears to have worked.

Comment: Your half of the data is in json and half seems to be raw html ,if you again `json_encode` , you will mess all data ,as the already encoded data will be encoded again. so to fix it you have 'json_decode' json part and add to string , then do `json_encode`. I am unable to see the links as Its prohibited in my region

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with:

```
<script>
<?php
  $json = '{ "call": "myFunction(\\\"<ul>                                                                                                                                 
    <li>Passwords are case-sensitive, that is the lower-case letter \\\"a\\\" is      diffe...\\\")" }';

  $json = str_replace("\n",   "\\\n", $json);
  echo "var str = '".$json."';";
?>

document.write(str);
str = JSON.parse(str);
alert(str.call);
</script>
```

In my testing, triple escaping the newline n keeps the formating in the html, but lets the string be parsed by JSON.

-C